# List Files in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to list all the jpg files in my blob. When I use this code

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount1 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnString"));
CloudBlobContainer container1 = blobClient.GetContainerReference(imageFolder);
var blobs = container1.ListBlobs();
```

All the files in that particular blob are listed

I have tried to modify the above code but the modified code does not list anything.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount1 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnString"));
CloudBlobContainer container1 = blobClient.GetContainerReference(imageFolder);
var blobs = container1.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobContainer>().OrderByDescending(b => b.Name).Where(b => b.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"));
```

Comment: `.OfType<CloudBlobContainer>()` - are you sure you have the right type?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I changed OfType<CloudBlobContainer>()  to OfType<CloudBlockBlob>() and it worked. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close out this question properly: The issue is that the query code is inadvertently checking for *containers* within the container, not *blobs* within the container:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount1 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ConnString"));
CloudBlobContainer container1 = blobClient.GetContainerReference(imageFolder);
var blobs = container1.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlobContainer>().OrderByDescending(b => b.Name).Where(b => b.Name.EndsWith(".jpg"));
```

The last line should be changed to:

```
var blobs = container1.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()...
```