# pointers for REST API To access or list files in the blob storage container

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm very new to microsoft azure. I have been given the task to list all the files in the azure blob storage container. 
Below are the details which i'm having for the task

i'm having below details:

Storage Account - accdevtesthw

Storage account type - blob

Container Name - Students

Folders - Marks & Details

Storage Account key -

Please let me know how to get the REST URL to list all the files in Marks folder in my container.

i tried with below URL, but failed with the error mentioned

```
https://accdevtesthw.blob.core.windows.net/Students/Marks?comp=list
```

error:

```
<Error>
        <Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code>
        <Message>
        Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid. RequestId:90a650f3-601e-008e-62b3-e3ab45000000 Time:2019-03-26T09:06:07.8146066Z
        </Message>
        <QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName>
        <QueryParameterValue>list</QueryParameterValue>
        <Reason/>a
        </Error>
```

I want to know how to frame RESTURL with the details i have been given

Comment: you want to just use the api you provided to list blobs(with tools like postman) or use code to list blobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding the 'prefix' parameter in the Uri. In your case I think you need:

```
https://accdevtesthw.blob.core.windows.net/Students?comp=list&prefix=Marks
```

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#uri-parameters

Comment: To make this work, I also had to add ```restype=container```: ```https://accdevtesthw.blob.core.windows.net/Students?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=Marks```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the suggestion mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929288/get-all-files-from-azure-blob-container-using-rest-api-i-am-already-tried-this) thread

The [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) operation enumerates the list of blobs under the specified container.

```html
Try this code.  Basically, the thing to do is check the type on each of the IListBlobItems returned:

var blobs = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobs.GetContainerReference("testcontainer");
container.CreateIfNotExist();
container.GetBlobReference("directory/blob.txt").UploadText(string.Empty);
container.GetBlobReference("blob.txt").UploadText(string.Empty);

var items = container.ListBlobs();

Console.WriteLine("Directories:");
foreach (var dir in items.OfType<CloudBlobDirectory>())
{
  Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", dir.Uri);
}

Console.WriteLine("Blobs:");
foreach (var blob in items.OfType<CloudBlob>())
{
  Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", blob.Uri);
}
```

Or  You may try this option too

```html
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("aaa");

            foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in container.ListBlobs())
            {
                if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory)
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)blobItem;
                    IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobs = directory.ListBlobs(true);
                    ICloudBlob bi;
                    foreach (var blob in blobs)
                    {
                        if (blob is CloudPageBlob)
                        {
                            bi = blob as CloudPageBlob;
                            Console.WriteLine(bi.Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(bi.Properties.LastModified.ToString());
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine(@"==========================");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

For more information you may refer to the suggestion mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549589/list-files-in-azure-blob-storage) link

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.